# Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting an error of `null` value in the following code in `MVC asp.net`;

```
  @Regex.Replace(Model.FullDescription, "<[^>]*>" ,"")
```

I am trying to replace any `HTML` tag with empty string. In popup window it shows result correctly without HTML tags, but on page it is showing above null value error.

Comment: Check the value of `Model.FullDescription` it will be `null`

Comment: @un-lucky it has value

Comment: It doesn't have value.

Comment: Ok if it has has null value then what is possible way to run this code with null value

Comment: @Qadeer for that see the my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are passing it a `null` as its first parameter and it tells you in error message:

> Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: input

Try to check it on error with null validation

```
@Regex.Replace(Model.FullDescription ?? "", "<[^>]*>" ,"")
```

Comment: @Qadeer Glad to have been of help